# Assigning a value to an option from a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a cash register type program. I've gotten as far as to add items to a dropdown list by typing into the input field and pressing the "Add" button. Now I'm trying to give an item that I've selected in the dropdown menu a value. For example, I add "Apple" to the list, I select it from the dropdown menu, type a price in an input field, then assign what's in the input field to the "Apple" by pressing a button. Here's how far I've gotten:

```js
function addProduct() {

    var list = document.createElement("OPTION");
    var name = document.getElementById("productName");

    list.innerHTML = name.value;
    name.value = "";

    document.getElementById("dropDown").appendChild(list);
}
```

```html
<p>Add new product</p>
<input type="text" id="productName" placeholder="product name here">
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Product" onclick="addProduct()">

<div>
    <p>Select a product then add the price per unit</p>
    <select id="dropDown"></select>
    <input type="text" id="productPrice" placeholder="price">
    <input type="button" value="Add Price" id="btnPrice" onlick="">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to assign the price as the `value` of the option?

Comment: @ThomasByy yes.

Comment: `list.value = document.getElementById("productPrice").value;`

Answer (score 0):

Create a script that will get the option being selected then assign its value. You can check the console to see that the value is being assigned successfully.

```js
function addProduct() {

    var list = document.createElement("OPTION");
    var name = document.getElementById("productName");

    list.innerHTML = name.value;
    name.value = "";

    document.getElementById("dropDown").appendChild(list);
}

function addPrice(){
  var price = document.getElementById('productPrice').value;
  var product = document.querySelector('option:checked');
  product.value = price;
  console.log("Name of Product: "+product.innerHTML+"\n"+"Price: "+ product.value);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Add new product</p>
    <input type="text" id="productName" placeholder="product name here">
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Product" onclick="addProduct()">
    
    <div>
      <p>Select a product then add the price per unit</p>
      <select id="dropDown"></select>
      <input type="text" id="productPrice" placeholder="price">
      <input type="button" value="Add Price" id="btnPrice" onclick="addPrice()">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the selected option, and then assign to its `value`.

```js
function addProduct() {
  var list = document.createElement("OPTION");
  var name = document.getElementById("productName");
  list.innerHTML = name.value;
  name.value = "";
  document.getElementById("dropDown").appendChild(list);
}

function addPrice() {
  var name = document.getElementById("productName");
  var option = name.options[name.selectedIndex];
  var price = document.getElementById("productPrice").value;
  option.value = price;
}
```

```html
<p>Add new product</p>
<input type="text" id="productName" placeholder="product name here">
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Product" onclick="addProduct()">

<div>
  <p>Select a product then add the price per unit</p>
  <select id="dropDown"></select>
  <input type="text" id="productPrice" placeholder="price">
  <input type="button" value="Add Price" id="btnPrice" onlick="addPrice()">
</div>
```